# LEFT JOIN Excel VBA ADODB not working

Tags: sql, vba, excel, join

I am trying to merge the data from two worsheets in in one workbook.
I have succesfully queried the data into two diffrent recordsets like so:

```
SELECT F1,F5,F12,F13,F37,F38 FROM [KAP$] WHERE F8 LIKE 'klima'
```

and

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8 FROM [Klima$A3:H899] WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL
```

Unfortunatly I have not found a way to "merge" the two recordsets.
However I noticed that the better way to archieve this would be to just query the two sheets at once using a left join. However I just can't get the syntax right. My last try was this:

```
SELECT
[KAP$].F1,
[KAP$].F5,
[KAP$].F12,
[KAP$].F13,
[KAP$].F37, 
[KAP$].F38,
[Klima$].F1,
[Klima$].F2,
[Klima$].F3,
[Klima$].F4, 
[Klima$].F5,
[Klima$].F6,
[Klima$].F7,
[Klima$].F8
FROM [KAP$] WHERE [KAP$].F8 LIKE 'Klima' LEFT JOIN [Klima$A3:H899] ON [KAP$].F1=[Klima$].F1
```

But as I have noticed there is more than one thing wrong with it... Any help is apreciated, I have been looking for a proper excel vba adodb guide for hours without success....

Thank you!

Edit: Here is some sample data:

KAP:

```
ID1  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID2  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID3  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID4  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID5  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID6  Info1  Info2  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
```

Klima:

```
ID1 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8
ID2 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8
ID3 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8
ID6 Info1  -  -   Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8
```

The merged tables should look like this:

```
ID1 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID2 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID3 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID4 Info1  Info2  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID5 Info1  Info2  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
ID6 Info1  Info2  Klima3  Klima4  Klima5  Klima6  Klima7  Klima8  KAPinfo1  KAPinfo2  KAPinfo3
```

Basically I want to overwrite the columns Info1 and Info2 in the right table (Klima) with the information from the left table (KAP) while keeping extra columns in the right table (Klima)

Comment: for each F1 you need the"merge" on the same row or on two (or more) rows .?. add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 4):

if you need  a left join  the sintax for join should be :

```
SELECT
[KAP$].F1,
[KAP$].F5,
[KAP$].F12,
[KAP$].F13,
[KAP$].F37, 
[KAP$].F38,
[Klima$A3:H899].F1,
[Klima$A3:H899].F2,
[Klima$A3:H899].F3,
[Klima$A3:H899].F4, 
[Klima$A3:H899].F5,
[Klima$A3:H899].F6,
[Klima$A3:H899].F7,
[Klima$A3:H899].F8
FROM [KAP$]
LEFT JOIN [Klima$A3:H899]   ON ([KAP$].F1=[Klima$A3:H899].F1)
WHERE   [KAP$].F8 LIKE 'Klima%'
```

*assuming that [Klima$A3:H899] is a valid  table  or equivalent*

Comment: Not working unfortunatly, "Syntax error in JOIN-Operation" #-2147217900

Comment: now there is a diffrent error (same error code) "join expression not supported" I tried brackets but no luck. This is so frustrating thank you for your help!

Comment: Now the error is a data type mismatch any idea? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: asnwer  updated  ..but be sure that you are compating the same data type

Comment: back to "syntax error in JOIN-Operation" this is so stupid, is there a diffrent approach to my problem? I have to use Excel... Thank you!

Comment: still data missmatch error, the cells F1 contain an alphanumeric value and both have the same data type theoretically

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT [KAP$].F1,
       [KAP$].F5,
       [KAP$].F12,
       [KAP$].F13,
       [KAP$].F37, 
       [KAP$].F38,
       [Klima$].F1,
       [Klima$].F2,
       [Klima$].F3,
       [Klima$].F4, 
       [Klima$].F5,
       [Klima$].F6,
       [Klima$].F7,
       [Klima$].F8
FROM
    (SELECT F1,F5,F12,F13,F37,F38 FROM [KAP$] WHERE F8 LIKE 'klima') AS [KAP$]
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8 FROM [Klima$A3:H899] WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL) AS [Klima$]
ON [KAP$].F1 = [Klima$].F1
```

Comment: excel is giving me a data type mismatch error :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: @l.wach Try edited answer. Also, if it doesn't work, try changing `'klima'` to`'%klima%'`.

Comment: @l.wach Make sure that both `F1` columns are of same datatype.